# Responsive jQuery plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a plug-in powered by jQuery that simplifies the developer's life to create responsive applications. It's flexible and I want to give to users a good syntax to write.

How can I improve this?

[GitHub](https://github.com/chiefGui/sensitivejs)

```
; (function ($) {
    var debug = {
        ranges: [],
        refreshRanges: function(ranges) {
            this.ranges = ranges;
        },
        invoke: function(reference) {
            console.log(this.warnings[reference].apply());
        },
        clean: function() {
            this.ranges = undefined;
        },
        warnings: {
            inRange: function () {
                return 'You\'re in range between ' + debug.ranges[0] + 'px and ' + debug.ranges[1] + 'px.';
            },
            outOfRange: function() {
                return 'You\'re out of range between ' + debug.ranges[0] + 'px and ' + debug.ranges[1] + 'px.';
            }
        }
    };

    var screen = {
            inRange: undefined,
            outOfRange: undefined,
            firstTimeResponsive: true,
            sensibilize: function(ranges, action, callback, debugging) {
                if (this.isInRange(ranges) === true) {
                    this.outOfRange = false;

                    if (this.inRange === false || (typeof this.inRange === 'undefined' && this.firstTimeResponsive === true)) {
                        action(device);

                        this.inRange = true;
                        this.firstTimeResponsive = false;

                        if (debugging === true) {
                            debug.refreshRanges(ranges);
                            debug.invoke('inRange');
                            debug.clean();
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    this.inRange = false;

                    if (this.outOfRange === false || (typeof this.outOfRange === 'undefined' && this.firstTimeResponsive === true)) {
                        if (this.firstTimeResponsive === false) {
                            callback(device);
                        }

                        this.outOfRange = true;
                        this.firstTimeResponsive = false;

                        if (debugging === true) {
                            debug.refreshRanges(ranges);
                            debug.invoke('outOfRange');
                            debug.clean();
                        }
                    };
                }
            },
            isInRange: function(ranges) {
                if (this.reached(ranges)) {
                    return true;
                };
            },
            reached: function(range) {
                var windowWidth = $(window).width();

                if (windowWidth >= range[0] && windowWidth <= range[1]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };

    var device = {
        identification: navigator.userAgent,
        isMobile: function() {
            return /mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        },
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (device.Android() || device.BlackBerry() || 
                    device.iOS() || device.Opera() || device.Windows());
        }
    };

    $.sensitive = function(ranges, action, callback, options) {
        var defaults = {
            debugging: false,
            handheldDevicesOnly: false,
            ultimateScreenWidth: 15360
        };

        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if (typeof ranges[1] === 'undefined') {
            ranges[1] = plugin.settings.ultimateScreenWidth;
        };

        if (plugin.settings.handheldDevicesOnly === true && device.isMobile() === false) {
            return null;
        };

        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            screen.sensibilize(ranges, action, callback, plugin.settings.debugging);
        }).trigger('resize');
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My 2 cents :

- Why jQuery, libraries targetting mobile should not require jQuery, #perfmatters
- Your github project should have a production version where debug is excluded, your code is 4215 bytes with debug feature, 3014 without debugging ( removing all debugging related code )
- Your code maintains both the value of `inRange` and `outOfRange`, you should only need 1 ?
- `this.firstTimeResponsive === true` can be replaced with `this.firstTimeResponsive`
- `this.inRange === false || (typeof this.inRange === 'undefined')` can be `!this.inRange`
- `isInRange` seems pointless, it's a wrapper around `reached` without added value ?
- `ranges` is an unfortunate parameter name, since you only pass 1 range ( from/to pair )
- `action` and `callback` are misleading as parameter names, how about `inRangeCallback` and `outOfRangeCallback` ?

From a design perspective, why do you track `firstTimeResponse` and also track resizing of the browser, it seems pointless. I think you need to test resizing.

Whereas this review seems harsh, I think the library can be put to good use, but it needs some serious clean up.

Comment: Do you think that `debugging` parameter is necessary? I mean, isn't an argument, it's just an option. `sensibilize: function(range, inRangeCallback, outOfRangeCallback, debugging) { ... }`

Comment: It's 25% less code without debugging code.

Comment: I followed your hint — I removed debugging. If you want to see the new version, [jump in](https://github.com/chiefGui/sensitivejs/blob/v0.4.0/dist/sensitive-0.4.0.js).

Answer (score 3):

I know names aren't hugely important but my 2 cents in addition to having already written some of what @tomdemuyt said (which I editted out):

- `clean` isn't very descriptive. It's also inconsistent. Based upon other names, a better fit would be `clearRanges`
- You don't always have to do `=== false` or `=== true` Please use truthy/falsiness. You're already doing this by not returning a value from your functions that either return true, or undefined. Undefined being falsy.
- As tomdemuyt said, you can simplify some of your functions. Instead of

  ```
  if (windowWidth >= range[0] && windowWidth <= range[1]) {
              return true;
          }
  ```

  You could use:

  ```
  return windowWidth >= range[0] && windowWidth <= range[1];
  ```

I agree with tomdemuyt that requiring this to be used with jQuery seems to contradict your description of it being "lightweight". Most of the code doesn't reference jQuery, I'd look into factoring out the jQuery dependence.